# The input type for uploading images does not work for material-ui dialog, how to fix this?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I just used the Form Dialog and input type="file" does not accept any files. Nothing happens when I click it. However, if i'll put it outside the Dialog, it works fine.

```
 <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
           Subscribe
          </Button>
          <Dialog
            open={open}
            onClose={handleClose}
            aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
          >
            <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Add New Product</DialogTitle>
            <DialogContent style={{ width: "450px" }}>
              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <TextField
                  autoFocus
                  margin="dense"
                  id="text"
                  label="Name"
                  type="text"
                  fullWidth
                />
              
              <input accept="image/*" type="file" />
              </form>
              
            </DialogContent>
            <DialogActions>
              <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
                Cancel
              </Button>
              <Button type="submit" color="primary">
                Save
              </Button>
            </DialogActions>
          </Dialog>
```

Comment: I requset you to share the minimal code to reproduce the error again

Comment: @saurav I edited it and posted the codes again. Thank you

Comment: @saurav oh wait, nevermind. Fixed it already.

Comment: How did you fix it? What was the issue?

Comment: @AjeetShah it was on my part, more like a typo. I accidentally wrapped the entire dialog with a Link for the next page. That's what caused the error

Comment: I still have that issue because my <dialog> is part of a custom js web-component